# proper domain for convex perspective function

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

Note: cross posted [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29590/proper-domain-for-convex-perspective-function)

The perspective of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $g$ is defined as $$g(x,t) = tf(x/t)$$ with $$\mathbf{\text{dom}}\, g = \{(x, t) : x/t \in \mathbf{\text{dom}}\, f, \,t > 0\}.$$

If I'm modeling a convex constraint of the form $g(x,t) \leq 0$ in a convex solver software, how do I ensure the domain constraint $t>0$ is satisfied? I tried $t \geq 0$, but for some problems, my $t^* = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $>$ constraints do not work well in numerical optimization software: how is the program supposed to distinguish between $0$, which is not allowed, and
$10^{-1000}$, which is?

I would replace the constraint $t > 0$ by $t \ge \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is some suitable small number.  If you end up with solutions with $t = \epsilon$ 
(no matter how small $\epsilon$ is), that may mean the problem with $t > 0$ does not actually achieve an optimum.

Comment: Thanks -- this was my approach so far, but your point about $t = \epsilon$ scares me as I've been observing this. Shouldn't the problem (at least theoretically) achieve an optimum (if it's feasible) with the constraint $t>0$ because the constraint is still convex?

Comment: For example, the following problem is convex but does not achieve an optimum: minimize $t$ subject to $t > 0$.

Comment: What about "$\inf$-ing" rather than minimizing? Then if we have continuity & compactness, we could say that using $t \geq 0$ is acceptable? That is, if $t=0$ is a solution for the $\inf$, then in some cases we can make an argument that it's the solution for the $\min$, right?